# $A$ be a real symmetric matrix of size $n$ ; is $I_n+A$ always non-singular ? Is $I_n - A$ always singular ?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix of size $n$ ; is $I_n+A$ always non-singular ? Is $I_n - A$ always singular ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even simpler counter-examples: $$A = 0 \implies I_n - A = I_n \text{ is nonsingular}$$ $$A = -I_n \implies I_n + A = 0 \text{ is singular}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$
       I= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 
        \end{pmatrix},
\quad
A= \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$ We have
$$
       I+A= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
which is clearly singular.

Take
$$
       I= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 
        \end{pmatrix},
\quad
A= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$ We have
$$
       I-A= \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 \\
        -1 & 0 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
which is clearly non-singular.